# Fastest way to propgate through a 2d Array C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have 2 large 2d arrays which is 100s*100s. which has one big loop to do the operation for several times. Inside it there is 3 loops; first loop store in `arr1` the sum of each cell in `arr2` multiplied by number, 2nd loop stream the 2 arrays to a file and the third loop store in `arr2` the sum of the two arrays divided by number.

The code explains better:

```
for(int i=1;i<x+1;i++) {//initialize
    for(int j=1;j<y+1;j++) {
        arr1[i][j]=i*j*5.5;
        arr2[i][j]=0.;
    }
}

for (int i=0;i<x+2;i++) {//padding
    vi[i][0]=5;
    vi[i][y+1]=-5;
}

for (int j=0;j<y+2;j++) {//padding
    vi[0][j]=10.;
    vi[x+1][j]=-10.;
}

for(int t=0;t<times;++t) {
    for(int i=1;i<x+1;++i) {
        for(int j=1;j<y+1;j++) {
            arr2[i][j]=(arr1[i+1][j]+arr1[i-1][j]+arr1[i][j-1]+arr1[i][j+1])*1.5;
        }
    }

    arr2[1][1]=arr2[1][y]=arr2[x][1]=arr2[x][y]=0.;

    for(int i=1;i<x+1;++i) {
        for(int j=1;j<y+1;j++) {
            arr1[i][j]=(arr1[i][j]+arr2[i][j])*0.5;

            if(arr2[i][j]+arr1[i][j]>5.)
                cout<<"\n"<<t<<"  "<<i-1<<" "<<j-1<<" "<<arr1[i][j]<<" "<<arr2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

the whole code works in more then 14s. How should I optimize the code to work in a fastest time possible.

Comment: You'll let us know how well expressions like  `arr2[i-1]` work out for you when `i` is zero on the initial loop iteration of `j`. Likewise on the opposite end when `i = (maxi-1)` and you dereference `arr2[i+1]`. You have similar problems with `j` when it is initially zero and you use expressions like `arr2[i][j-1]`. Something tells me computation time is the least of your worries.

Comment: I have edited the code. the arrays is have padding rows and columns to avoid the special cases in the edges.

Comment: That would be good, because as written now, the `arr1[0][0]` value will be used, but *never* change.

Comment: I reput the code now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 3rd array to temporary store the array values of arr2 for the next run.
After the first loop is done, you overwrite arr2 with the temporary array - like this you don't need the second loop. You will save half of the time.

```
for (n=0;n<x;n++)
{
   for (i=0;i<maxi;i++)
   {
      for (j=0;j<maxj;j++)
      {
         arr1[i][j]=(arr2[i+1][j]+arr2[i-1][j]+arr2[i][j+1]+arr2[i][j-1])*1.5;
         arr_tmp[i][j] = (arr1[i][j]+arr2[i][j])*0.5;
      }
   }
   arr2 = arr_tmp;
}
```

Comment: Code would probably speak volumes. And note that `arr[2]` is never written-to in the biggest time consumer of this code: the triple loop, so I'm not sure where the savings are. Maybe show us?

Comment: As I understand the code, there is one main loop over two parts. Each part consists of two nested loops. Part 1 and part 2 are consuming the same time...

Comment: I did your suggestion but the code still slow. I think because the first loop is consuming more time. I think because a cache issue. How can I make it cache friendly?

Comment: +1 I believe you're right. It was the formatting of the code that threw me from that. I'm not sure the results are the same, especially because of the undefined behavior when addressing `[i-1]` and `[j-1]` arrays when `i` and `j` are zero, but no more so than the OP's original broken code. I think this will work.

Comment: the arrays are padded to avoid the special cases in the edges.

Comment: @M Khashoggi: Please do consider what WhozCraig wrote about undefined behaviour... I think there shouldn't be any caching issues. Or is this running on a 8032? ;) Maybe you should show us the whole piece of code. How did you initialize the array and so on.

Comment: If it's a cache issue, you could try swapping the `i` and the `j` loop - one direction will run along cache lines, the other will not (and thus will force more cache misses). See which one runs faster

Comment: `there is another loop that has an instruction to stream n, arr1 and arr2`- this is not the issue? Did you comment out the streaming part?

Comment: I put the full code now.. I tried both orders, [i][j] works faster than [j][i]

Comment: `if(arr2+arr1>5.)` - it's a while since i did plain ANSI C++ coding. What should this expression do? How fast is the code, if you do no streaming to cout?

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong. I edited my post. It actually check cell by cell arr2[i][j]+arr1[i][j>5.

Answer (score 1):

Note: *The OP's code has changed dramatically in response to comments about padding and such.  There wasn't really anything wrong with the original code -- which is what I have based this answer on.*

Assuming that your 2D arrays are indexed *row-major* (the first index is the row, and the second index is the column), your memory accesses are already in the correct order for best cache utilization (you are accessing nearby elements as you progress).  Your latest code calls this assumption into question since you seem have renamed 'maxi' to be 'x' which would suggest that you are indexing a *column-major* 2D array (which is very non-standard for C/C++).

It wasn't specified how you were declaring your 2D arrays, and that could make a difference, but **I got a big improvement by converting your implementation to use raw pointers**.  I also eliminated the second loop (from your original post) by combining the operations and alternating the direction for each iteration.  I changed the weighting coefficients so that they added up to 1.0 so that I could test this more easily (by generating an image output).

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> > Array2D;

void run( int x, Array2D & arr2 )
{

   Array2D temp = arr2; // easy way to create temporary array of the correct size

   int maxi=arr2.size(), maxj=arr2[0].size();

   for (int n=0;n<x;n++)
   {
      Array2D const & src = (n&1)?temp:arr2; // alternate direction
      Array2D & dst = (n&1)?arr2:temp;
      for (int i=1;i<maxi-1;i++)
      {
         double const * sp0=&src[i-1][1], * sp1=&src[i][1], * sp2=&src[i+1][1];
         double * dp=&dst[i][1];
         for (int j=1;j<maxj-1;j++)
         {
            dp[0]=(sp0[0]+sp1[-1]+4*sp1[0]+sp1[+1]+sp2[0])*0.125;
            dp++, sp0++, sp1++, sp2++;
         }
      }
   }

   if ( (x&1) ) arr2=temp; // copy the result back if the iteration count was odd
} /**/
```

Other things you could look into (somewhat platform-dependent):

- `restrict` keyword for pointers (not standard C++)
- prefetch requests -- a compiler/processor specific way of reducing memory access latency
- make sure you have enabled optimizations when you compile
- depending on the size of the array, you might find it advantageous to columnize your algorithm to make better use of available cache

Take advantage of available compute resources (very platform-dependent):

- Create a [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)-based implementation
- Take advantage of your multi-core CPU -- OpenMP
- Take advantage of your GPU -- OpenCL

Comment: I think the coefficients for arr2[i]=sum(arr1[i + x] .* w[x]) are 0.5 for the middle term and 0.75 for the others.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: I chose my own coefficients because I wanted them to sum to 1.0 so that the average wouldn't change on every iteration.